# How would you calculate the speed of a bouncing ball that loses energy with each collision?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a hard time grasping this question. I’m not looking for a solution to this problem, but rather how would you approach this?

The question goes like this.

“ *We look at ball, that’s bouncing on a table. After each collision with the table, it only has 1/9 of its energy left. We assume the ball doesn’t lose energy while it’s in the air, which means, that when the ball collides with the table again after a jump, it has the same speed in the different direction, that it had when it left the table.

Remember, the formula for the ball’s kinetic energy is 1/2mv^2.

We assume, that the ball first collides with the table with a velocity of v0 = 1 m/s.*

**Show, that the next time the ball collides with the table after the first collision, its speed is v1 = 1/3 m/s, and find a formula for its speed vn after n collisions. ** “

Comment: First, make some notation for the energy after each bounce so we can sequence them, I'll use $E_0,E_1,...$ and so on. Then note that the equation gives $E_1=E_0/9$. Now use that the mass of the ball being constant to calculate the velocity $v_1$. Does that get you started?

Comment: Why was this tagged as set theory? I see nothing in this question that could explain that tag but my edit removing it was rejected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote $t_1$ the time of the first impact.
The ball is losing a fraction of its energy
after impact: $E(t_1^+)=\frac19 E(t_1^-)$.

We deduce
$v^2(t_1^+)=\frac19 v^2(t_1^-)$
and thus because of the conservation of energy
in the time interval $[t_1,t_2]$,
we obtain the result
$v(t_2^-)=v(t_1^+)=\frac13 v(t_1^-)$.
The rest follows

Comment: That explains it perfectly! Thanks :) As for the formula for the velocity v_n, am I right in assuming v_n = 1/3v_n-1 for nth collision?

Comment: yes! the same scheme repeats at each collision.